# Hide all months except current

Tags: show-hide

I have a sheet with columns for each month.  Column C is January  (cell C1 = 1), Column D is February (cell D1 = 2), etc.

I'm trying to hide all of the month columns except the current month.  I think I'm getting close but the logic escapes me.

Suggestions?...JD

```
   function HideTheMonths(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sum Remaining");
  var date = new Date();                
  var mo1 = date.getMonth();

  var mons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
  var curmons = mons[mo1];
  for (var x = 3; x < 15; x++){
    var c = s.getRange(1, x)
   if (curmons = c) {
     var datarange = s.hideColumns(x);    

   }     
  }
```

}

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Hi Wyatt, I should have been more clear.  I'm trying to learn google scripting with google sheets.  I think the language is javascript.  I actually received help for this question on another site:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/PWlz5s6sVrE;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/authorid$3AAPn2wQfWs6k5AGRhB-lBmfhEiSNf7SH9KvdPbRCaV9QEA-BCIXmZqIlWbu2XSQQct9TAHJvYt2Gf%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false